# How to add dynamically button and its event to the windows form?

Tags: c#

dynamically add button with coordinates X=100, Y=200; and by click, the form must change background color to red, by the second click to green.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form

{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private int X = 100;
    private int Y = 200;
    Button btn = new Button();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Location = new Point(X, Y);
        btn.Text = "Click";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(Mouse_Click);
    }


    private void Mouse_Click(Object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        // what to do here to make button change Form color?
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is really a bad question for this site. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] as a result..

Comment: @Geo Man Looks like you already have your solution so why are u asking/

Comment: private void Mouse_Click(Object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        // what to do here to make button change Form color?
    }
:\

Comment: @GeoMan Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066616/how-to-add-dynamically-button-and-its-event-to-the-windows-form/19066689#19066689

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Create new instance of button
Button btn = new Button();
//Set button Location
btn.Location = new Point(100, 200);
//Set button event handler
btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
//Add button to Form
this.Controls.Add(btn);

void btn_click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

To change form color

```
void btn_click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    //or
    this.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
}
```